# GitHub - Show user's starred repos

Tags: github

I know that there is an [API endpoint](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#list-repositories-being-starred) of repos that are starred by a particular user...

Is there an app endpoint that lists all starred repos by a user?

I've tried:

- http://github.com/ddavison/starred
- http://github.com/users/ddavison/starred

to no avail.. i've run out of ideas.  Is there an app endpoint that shows repos that a user has starred?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The URL I was looking for was this format:

```
https://github.com/stars/<user>
```

Answer (score 6):

This should do the trick!

Query the GitHub api with the below URL. This is equivalent to an HTTP GET

https://api.github.com/users/ddavison/starred

Comment: A previous answerer had deleted his question.  The proper URL i was looking for, was: http://github.com/stars/ddavison